# DocuSign Payments REST API create Tab and Save Payment Method

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using the Docusign REST API and attempting to create a payment tab that will save the signer's payment method with Stripe.

There is some information in the Docusign API Guide, and on StackOverflow, explaining how to *collect* payments using the API, but I haven't found any resources explaining how to *save and authorize* the payment method for future billing, although this functionality is available when creating an envelope manually on the Docusign website.  (To do it on the Docusign site, you simply click Standard Fields--> Payment Item --> Payment Type --> Save Payment Method.)  Since the functionality is available on the site, it should also be possible to implement through the API as well.

The following code was taken from another question on stackoverflow, and it works for setting up a tab for *collecting* a payment, but again without *saving* the payment method with Stripe for future charges:

```
"numberTabs": [{
    "xPosition": 268,
    "yPosition": 142,
    "documentId": "12345",
    "recipientId": "1",
    "pageNumber": 1,
    "value": 250,
    "maxLength": 4000,
    "width": 80,
    "height": 16,
    "tabLabel": "PaymentFixed 646b5192-a101-4cdc-a7e5-5e9bd1b80612",
    "paymentItemName": "Test Item Name",
    "paymentItemCode": "54321",
    "paymentItemDescription": "Test Item Details"
}],
"formulaTabs": [{
    "paymentDetails": {
        "currencyCode": "USD",
        "gatewayAccountId": "8cfb9a83-1f4c-40b1-b7a9-dd382ee0ca7d",
        "lineItems": [{
            "amountReference": "PaymentFixed 646b5192-a101-4cdc-a7e5-5e9bd1b80612",
            "name": "Test Item Name",
            "description": "Test Item Details",
            "itemCode": "54321"
        }]
    },
    "formula": "([PaymentFixed 646b5192-a101-4cdc-a7e5-5e9bd1b80612]) * 100",
    "recipientId": "1",
    "documentId": "12345",
    "tabLabel": "PaymentReceipt e47eed9a-85ca-4094-8d0f-50e51d5d1ee0",
    "xPosition": 0,
    "yPosition": 0,
    "pageNumber": 1,
    "required": true,
    "locked": true,
    "hidden": true
}]
```

How can I modify this code so to both collect the payment and save the payment method for future billing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass `"paymentOption": "save_and_authorize"` to collect the one-time payment and also to save payment method on Stripe. Also you need to add a TextTab to show Save Payment Method on the signing screen, complete code to collect one-time payment and save payment method will look like below:

```
{
    "compositeTemplates": [
        {
            "document": {
                "documentBase64": "<Base64>",
                "documentId": "1",
                "fileExtension": "docx",
                "name": "Doc1"
            },
            "inlineTemplates": [
                {
                    "recipients": {
                        "signers": [
                            {
                                "email": "email@gmail.com",
                                "name": "John Doe",
                                "recipientId": "88089475",
                                "tabs": {
                                    "textTabs": [
                                        {
                                            "tabLabel": "PaymentFuture 53d3ce8e-a043-4d0a-93ff-37eee94d3555",
                                            "documentId": "1",
                                            "pageNumber": 1,
                                            "recipientId": "88089475",
                                            "xPosition": 201,
                                            "yPosition": 219,
                                            "locked": true
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "numberTabs": [
                                        {
                                            "tabLabel": "PaymentFixed 91684e58-85c6-4441-be08-efebac5476b8",
                                            "value": 10,
                                            "maxLength": 4000,
                                            "width": 84,
                                            "height": 22,
                                            "pageNumber": 1,
                                            "documentId": "1",
                                            "recipientId": "88089475",
                                            "paymentItemName": "Name1",
                                            "paymentItemCode": "Code1",
                                            "paymentItemDescription": "Details1",
                                            "xPosition": 201,
                                            "yPosition": 158
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "formulaTabs": [
                                        {
                                            "tabLabel": "PaymentReceipt 7a59b203-d9e8-4e3b-8b4d-776d8869cc30",
                                            "roundDecimalPlaces": 0,
                                            "formula": "([PaymentFixed 91684e58-85c6-4441-be08-efebac5476b8]) * 100",
                                            "hidden": true,
                                            "pageNumber": 1,
                                            "paymentDetails": {
                                                "currencyCode": "USD",
                                                "gatewayAccountId": "1d0702f5-f317-4af7-835d-1c8769434fae",
                                                "gatewayName": "Stripe",
                                                "paymentOption": "save_and_authorize",
                                                "lineItems": [
                                                    {
                                                        "amountReference": "PaymentFixed 91684e58-85c6-4441-be08-efebac5476b8",
                                                        "name": "Name1",
                                                        "description": "Details1",
                                                        "itemCode": "Code1"
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "amountReference": "PaymentFuture 53d3ce8e-a043-4d0a-93ff-37eee94d3555",
                                                        "name": "Monthly Payment $50",
                                                        "description": "Monthly Payment Desc",
                                                        "itemCode": "505050"
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            },
                                            "recipientId": "88089475",
                                            "documentId": "1",
                                            "xPosition": 0,
                                            "yPosition": 0
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "sequence": "2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "status": "sent",
    "emailSubject": "Payment Authorize"
}
```