# Docusign and Stripe integration - Payments are created without a customer

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, docusignapi

I'm trying to integrate the Docusign eSignature API with Stripe.
I've created a [Quickstart](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/) application and have successfully run through the process, signing the contract and making a test payment.

However, I noticed that the payment in Stripe does not have a customer object attached to it:
[image]

I'd like to know if it's possible to specify a customerId, or create one as part of the process. I did notice that the PaymentDetails constructor accepts a customerId parameter, but I could not see any relevant documentation for this, and specifying it in my request didn't seem to make any difference.

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dan,
For regular payments that are one time and right away - DocuSign will not create a customer record. This is "by design" and is meant to support quick payments without any customer record.
You can set recurring/future payments and then you'll get customer records when you set the gateway. If you want, your recurring payment or future payment can be just one time in the near future and then you can achieve what you want and get a customer record.

Comment: Thanks, I found what I was looking for here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57187748/862390